# Best Practice to prevent form abuse Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

What is the best way to limit form submissions in Django?
The form should be only submitted 5 times from the same IP in one hour, is there a way to do that in Django?

I tried [Django Ratelimit](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) but it doesn't really work, because the traffic doesn't get blocked.

Comment: "The form should be only submitted 5 times from the same IP in one hour"—be careful with this. You are probably using IP address as a proxy for something else (users? families? companies?), but the same user can easily have different IP addresses (via mobile phone, VPN, their ISP giving them a new address, etc.) and _many_ people can share an IP address (e.g. a hundred people in one office building). What is your actual goal? I suggest you read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: That's true. The actual goal is to limit the submissions of a form, for example to prevent a DDOS/DOS or Spam Attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up answer.

I used Memcache to check if a user submitted the same form more than five times in a specific timeframe. Worked very well and is quite simple to do.